# PHP separate paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a code for wordpress to separate paragraph using PHP. The objective is to split the content of the post into an array and echo them accordingly.

Here are my code

```
<?php
    $content = "<p>123</p> <p>456</p> <p>789</p>"
    $p = explode("</p>", $content);

    $i=0;
    //echo first 2 elements
    foreach ($p as $para) {
        echo $para;
        array_shift($p); //remove the first element
        $i++; //increase the element count by 1
        if ($i == 2){ break;} //if element has reach 2 meaning second paragraph, stop loop.
    }
    echo "<br>Break here<br>";
    //echo the rest of the element
    foreach ($p as $para) {
        echo $para;
    }
?>
```

Replace this

```
$content = "<p>123</p> <p>456</p> <p>789</p>"
```

With the following

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
```

to retrieve the content of the post with paragraph tag.

I am able to achieve my result but I am just worry of the consequences such as system overload.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, what you're trying to accomplish, is adding a couple of `<br>` tags after the first two paragraphs?

If so, this can be done alot simpler using the preg_replace method:

```
$content = "<p>123</p> <p>456</p> <p>789</p>";
echo preg_replace('/<\/p>/', '</p><br><br>', $content, 2);
```

Comment: Yes. I am trying to insert custom content depending on the custom field is inserted, ie. banner, gallery, quotes. The code provided make 2 line break after each paragraph and for some strange reason before the first paragraph as well.